# SEO friendly URLs to replace the old URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my site I currently use URLs like:

`http://sitname.in/category.php?active=1&filter=All`

I want the entire URL to be replaced with

`http://sitname.in/category`

That means the parameters should pass but a clean URL should be displayed in the sense that the in URL should not be displayed

Tell me how to create an .htaccess file completely and the additional files that should be required in order to create this seo friendly URLs and I don't want the old URL across the site that should be even hyperlinked clicked should display the new URL

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method in .htaccess is this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category$ /category.php?active=1&filter=All [L]
```

Remeber, any anchor should point now to www.mysite.com/category